# How to hide function parameter missing type notice?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code mostly for TypeScript development. Since 1.30 release I started getting this three dots mark next to functions with no defined type - [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akxcS.png). When I hover over, I get notice "Parameter X implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.". My simple question is - how to get rid of these without defining type? I don't have time to refactor everything now and this marking is annoying to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the "noImplicitAny" to `false` in your tsconfig file, or run tsc with the `--noImplicitAny` flag.

```
"noImplicitAny": "false"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `settings.json` file, add:

```
"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false
```

Or just look for the field called *Javascript › Suggestion Actions: Enabled* in your settings panel and untick the checkbox.

You can disable suggestion actions in TypeScript files, too — look for the setting called *TypeScript › Suggestion Actions: Enabled*.

Comment: Wouldn't this disable all the suggested actions (like removing unused methods and stuff like that)?

Comment: @AntoineBoisier-Michaud Correct! It will.